# How to segment characters from image of handwritten words

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying trying to find the bounding box for individual characters in the image of a word .  [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6YIS.png)

```
a = img[:,:,0]
b = img[:,:,1]
c = img[:,:,2]

s = a + b + c

h = s.sum(axis = 0)

min_peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(inv_data, np.arange(1,10))
```

I tried to find the boundaries along horizontal axis by finding the the local maximum of summation along vertical axis(0 black pixel and 255 white pixel)  output i able to get is .  [ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omMjI.png)

is there a better way to segment?

Comment: Did you search for something better? What did you find?

Comment: I found some for online handwritten data like in "Multi-language handwritten recognition". not much for images.